# Как скрыть окно браузера у Edge

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

Selenium Driver у EdgeOptions не обладает функцией AddArgument
Можно ли как-то скрыть окно браузера?

Answer (score 0):

Решено нужно ставить: Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools а не OpenQA.Selenium.Edge

Comment: Вообще еще есть WebView2 контрол, который и есть Edge